# How to upload a file using the file_file_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to upload file in form but do not want its field inside a model.
so using the file_filed_tag

```
at view:
 <%= form_tag services_datainterchange_path, method: :post, remote: true do %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :file %>
          <%= file_field_tag :file, required: true, class: "form-control", id: "upload_file" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :name %>
          <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, required: true, class: "form-control", id: "upload_file_name" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :source_type %>
          <%= select_tag :source_type, options_for_select(ApplicationRecord::SOURCE_TYPE), class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :final_type %>
          <%= select_tag :final_type, options_for_select(ApplicationRecord::FINAL_TYPE), class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

At controller:

```
  directory = "public/job_files"
  Find.find( directory ) do |fpath|
    if FileTest.file?( fpath )
      fpath.clone(params[:file])
    end
  end
```

But file not upload the parameter do get submit of form.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
  name = params['file'].original_filename

  uploaded_io = params['file']
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'job_files', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
```